# Find "complete cases" with awk

Tags: awk

Using `awk`, how can I output the lines of a file that have all fields non-null without manually specifying each column?

**foo.dat**

```
A||B|X
A|A|1|
|1|2|W
A|A|A|B
```

Should return:

```
A|A|A|B
```

In this case we can do:

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '$1 != "" && $2 != "" && $3 != "" && $4 != "" { print }' foo.dat
```

But is there a way to do this without specifying each column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over all fields and skip the record if any of the fields are empty:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { if (!$i) next } }1' foo.dat
A|A|A|B
```

`if (!$i)` is "if field `i` is not non-empty", and `1` is short for "print the line", but it is only hit if `next` was not executed for any of the fields of the current line.

Answer (score 0):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk -F\| 'gsub(/[^|]+(\||$)/,"&")==NF' file
A|A|A|B
```

`print` record if there are `NF` times `|` terminating (non-empty, `|`-excluding) strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!/\|\|/&&!/\|$/&&!/^\|/' file

A|A|A|B
```